# Why there is "overflow" required in the code?

Tags: html, css

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_navbar

The above link contain the practice background of W3school.
In the left side code,under style there is "ul" where the "overflow" property have been used.
My question is,when i remove the overflow,whole menu disappears.
Its not a problem, but i am not getting why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The browser needs to know the limits in which to produce the bar. Since there is no width indicated it needs to have something to tell it how far it can go.

Setting overflow to hidden makes it so the data just doesn't show past the page width.

Setting it to scroll allows the data to go "off" the page and the user can scroll to view it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my question was why the menu is disappearing.

Comment: Because when you don't tell it how to display it won't display.

Comment: And as u said, I wrote the width but still i cant see the menu unless i hover over it, Just i cant understand the reason for its disappearance. :-(

Comment: Thanks, i get it. I use Display:inline-block with width:100%, got the same result. thank u sir. A lot of help.

Comment: display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
Use this instead of overflow if it's a big deal lol. Overflow just means it will display across the screen.

Comment: Well, that was oddly weird timing. We submitted basically the same comment at the same time, lol.